# batch file: how to rename part of multiple directories?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm new to batch files and I've been asked to create one which will rename part of multiple directories.  For example, I need to rename directories as follows:

> ```
> ahhh111\ rename to aggg111\
> ahhh222\ rename to aggg222\
> ahhh333\ rename to aggg333\  and so on ...
> ```

I thought I could use `move` with wildcards but keep getting syntax errors;
e.g. `move "*hhh*" "*ggg*"` throws up a syntax error :-(

How can I do this please?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: code is as above using move command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`move` does not accept wildcards when moving/renaming directories.

However, you can use a [`for /D` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to iterate through the matching directories and [sub-string replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) to build the new name. For the latter to work in a loop, [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is required:

```cmd
for /D %%D in ("?hhh*") do (
    set "PDIR=%%~fD" & set "NAME=%%~nxD"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    move "!PDIR!" "!NAME:hhh=ggg!"
    endlocal
)
```

Note that this approach replaces every occurrence of `hhh` by `ggg` in the directory names.